# Получение высоты объекта

Tags: координаты, геометрия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть данные: все координаты объекта в пространстве(кроме высоты), дистанция до объекта, все собственные координаты и угол наклона к объекту, как получить эту самую высоту объекта?
я слишком плох в геометрии чтобы понять это

Примерный рисунок для ясности (Есть информация: x объекта, z объекта, a(угол наклона от меня до объекта), дистанция от меня до объекта и собственные координаты x y z, как найти y объекта?)

Comment: Нарисуйте чертёж. Описание ваше не слишком чёткое. И - это имеет отношение к программированию?

Comment: По сути не особо имеет отношение к программированию, но использую в коде.
Сейчас добавлю примерный рисунок к вопросу

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял:

```
dist^2 = dx^2+dy^2+dz^2   
|dy| = sqrt(dist^2 - dx^2 - dz^2)
```

где `dx` - разность X-координат объекта и наблюдателя и так далее.

Угол (между направлением на объект и чем?) поможет уточнить знак разности y-координат

Comment: честно, не знаю как объяснить.
есть трёхмерное пространство, в нём 2 точки, первая это я, вторая - объект.
Я могу определить свои координаты полностью, но координаты объекта нет, для объекта могу получить лишь угол направления(относительно себя) по горизонтали и по вертикали, а также дистанцию до объекта от себя, отсюда вопрос: как получить полные координаты объекта?

Comment: Для известных `x объекта, z объекта,` ответ подходит

Answer (score 0):

Все, чтобы определить координаты вашего объекта у вас есть. Если мы говорим о Декартовых координатах, то можно определиться со следующими исходными данными:

1. Координаты наблюдателя (т.е. вас) в общей системе координаты x1, y1, z1.
2. Расстояние от точки наблюдения до объекта - dist
3. Угол от плоскости x1Oy1 (скажем так, это плоскость параллельная общей системы координат xOy) - alpha.
4. Угол по горизонтали (если я правильно понимаю, что вы имели ввиду) - beta  - угол между АС и координатной прямой Ox1 (она параллельна Ох).
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   Решение.
   Итак ваш объект, это вершина В с координатами x2, y2, z2 которые мы должны выяснить.
   Треугольник АВС является прямоуогольным (плоскость х1Оу1  параллельна плоскости хОу, а т.С является проекцией точки В на плоскость х1Оу1.
   sin(alpha) = BC/AB = (z2-z1)/dist ,вы знаете угол, значит z2 = sin(alpha)*dist + z1;
   sin(beta) = СС1/AC = CC1/(cos(alpha) * AB) = (y2 - y1)/(cos(alpha) * dist), отсюда
   у2= sin(beta) * cos (alpha) * dist + y1;
   А уж как найти теперь х2, есть "33 варианта" Можно так:
   dist^2 = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 +  (z2-z1)^2. Тут неизвестно только x2-x1.
   х2 = х1 + sqrt(dist^2 - (y2-y1)^2 - (z2-z1)^2).
   По поводу знаков, тут смотрите сами. Но на знаки вам укажут градусы углов.